# Increasing the console font-size

Tags: command-line, fonts

I am not using the GUI to work in Ubuntu but rather I am using command line interface but the problem is that the font size in command line interface is very small. How can I increase the font size?

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name or monospace-font-name

Comment: @ParsaMousavi This will change the font but I want increase the font size.

Comment: You should add the font-size in front of that : for instance : 'Ubuntu,  10'

Comment: Please add your first comment to the question via clicking the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1244778/edit) button.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi i am not getting it why dont you write the answer briefly i would help everyone.

Comment: Sorry at the first glance I didn't understand your problem correctly. You don't want to use GUI at all. So my answer is incorrect. I'll post another one regarding the console font-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the console font-size and you have to edit the settings in the `/etc/default/console-setup` file . Here's mine :

```
# Consult the console-setup(5) manual page.

ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"

CHARMAP="UTF-8"

CODESET="guess"
FONTFACE="Fixed"
FONTSIZE="8x16"

VIDEOMODE=
```

You should manually change the line `FONTSIZE=`.

Permitted values are explained in the [manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-console-setup/) :

> ```
>   FONTFACE and FONTSIZE
>           Valid font faces are: VGA (sizes  8x8,  8x14,  8x16,  16x28  and
>           16x32),  Terminus  (sizes  6x12, 8x14, 8x16, 10x20, 12x24, 14x28
>           and 16x32), TerminusBold (sizes 8x14, 8x16, 10x20, 12x24,  14x28
>           and  16x32),  TerminusBoldVGA  (sizes  8x14 and 8x16), and Fixed
>           (sizes  8x13,  8x14,  8x15,  8x16   and   8x18).    If   however
>           CODESET=Ethiopian,  then  the  available font faces are Goha and
>           GohaClassic, each in sizes 8x12, 8x14 and 8x16.
> ```

But depending on your screen resolution , it might be small for you even after increasing it to maximum.

Comment: yes it is still small.i think screen resolution is the problem

Comment: @SreeHari In 4K screens unfortunately even the largest console font is small. I don't know why they haven't made it more flexible. VGA font has the maximum size of 16x32 . Have you tried that ?

Comment: Bro it's working I forget to restart....my bad...

Comment: Try 10x20 its perfect.